# JAXB Annotation to retrieve object as XML

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to use JAXB annotation `@XmlElement` on function which returns a object.

Function is:

```
@XmlElement(name= "properties")
public Object getX(XType x){
   return new ListimplementClass(x.getList());
}
```

Its returning only `<properties/>`, not the content inside.

Could you please help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [XmlSeeAlso](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) annotation as this might help. Your ListimplementClass must also have the appropriate JAXB annotations.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for response. @XmlSeeAlso resolved other issues.. :) I found Jaxb can not resolve object type during runtime and hence its not giving output for "Object". It should be specify particular implementation. In my case its majorly List<T> so changing type from Object to List solved the issue.